ASP.NET API with Cookie authentication recursion when forbidden
I am trying to implement a simple API with cookie authentication. I would like to have 403 and 401 when user is unauthorized and 401 when he is unauthenticated accordingly.
When I am trying to access the protected endpoint for which I don't have enough rights, I get into a recursion.
So basically if I am returning a http 403, I am getting into recursion.
Here is a very simple repo to reproduce:
The flow is login ->  try to access GetAuthorizedDataAdmins (it requires to have role "Admins") we only have "Admin".
Put the brake point on forbidden endpoint and you will see the recursion.
Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug?
It is so easy to reproduce that I cannot believe wasn't fixed before.
Repo to reproduce

You need to ensure that the AccessDeniedPath path actually exist.
.AddCookie(o =>
            {
                o.AccessDeniedPath = "/authentication/forbidden";
                o.LoginPath = "/authentication/unauthorized";
            });

right now the public class AuthorizatuinController : ControllerBase has a spelling error.
Also, this page should usually be a "access denied" HTML page. Also often decorated with [AllowAnonymous], to ensure that you don't need to be authenticated to view it.
You will find a lot resources related to this on my blog at https://nestenius.se/

Spelling error in AuthorizatuinController does not matter in this case since path to "AccessDeniedPath" is located at AuthenticationController which has a correct spelling.
So I don`t really understand how does it matter.
Plus AuthenticationController has no authorize attribute which pretty much means that it is under the [AllowAnonymous] state.
Plus I am not using blazor, I am going to use one of the frameworks for client like vue/react so I just want to return 403 response without any html in it

ok, can you reach /authentication/forbidden from the browser? that page needs to be reachable without any auth.
